Define color using local variable
Using this post, I created a variable in my file. Now I want to use it to define a background color in my array :
:first-color: #C0FFEE

[%noheader]
|===
h|{set:cellbgcolor:{first-color}} My Title
|{set:cellbgcolor} First cell
|===

But It did not work, all I have is an extra "}" in my title :

Is there a way to use variable to define my backgroung color ?

Since my previous answer may be useful in other contexts where CSS styling is supported, I'd rather not modify it and recommend a new solution. What do you think about creating a theme?
Like in this YAML configuration file. You can name it my-theme.yml:
page:
  background-color: #ffffff

table:
  head:
    background-color: $first-color

base:
  font-color: #333333

Now, this is your asciidoc file:
:first-color: #C0FFEE

[%noheader,cols="100%"]
|===
h|My Title
|First cell
|===

And when converting to PDF, use the theme file:
asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-theme=my-theme.yml your-file.adoc


Does your output support CSS styling so you can maybe do something like this?
:first-color: #C0FFEE

[%noheader,cols="100%"]
|===
h|[.custom-bg]#My Title#
|First cell
|===

[source,css]
----
<style>
.custom-bg {
  background-color: #C0FFEE;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
----


I've try but it seems that my output does not support CSS styling.  The source block appears in my pdf.
